# Why my page is taking too much white space in Rectjs

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

This page (page URL -https://runingproject.netlify.app) is showing good without any white space between two images  if open the page inside
the laptop but when I open it on mobile it is taking too much space as the below-attached pic is showing.

laptop showing pic- [laptop loading page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlydQ.jpg)

mobile showing pic  -[Mobile loading page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlJUL.jpg)

Here is my source code link - https://github.com/sunil7117/demo.git

**Please note:** Inside "mainComponent" folder, there are two components and both are some.

Comment: `height: 90vh` is the culprit. [Here's the proof](https://i.ibb.co/G0rD5nT/image.png)

Comment: Please read [ask], where it notes, "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to ... then do so - but **also copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS." See also [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/)

Answer (score 1):

I read your code and classes.
I see you use static height 90vh for main component body but your navbar has default material ui height size.
In this case your navbar height have been responsive and your body is static.
My solution is using static height for navbar or responsive height for body.
If you dont understand tell me help you more accurate
One way is like below

```
<AppBar position="static" sx={{ height: '10vh' }} >
...
</AppBar>
```

And if you have footer you can divide extra 10vh between footer and navbar.
The other way is a little bit complicated that have to determine all your body component to full page correctly.
In this case if you have just simple image you can fit width of image and allow fit the image size.

Comment: how to achieve  this think please help me more ..thank you

Comment: Please read [answer], the section titled "Answer well-asked questions".